# Return within Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have been playing around with Parse for the past 24 hours. I find that the `PFGeoPoint`feature is really powerful, however, it takes around 1.5 seconds to grab the current location. Because of this, you have to run other queries within the same block operation that require the current location as a parameter in your scheme.

I have been struggling with `return query` because it's saying that the method gives `incompatible block pointer types sending 'PFQuery' to parameter of type 'void PFGeoPoint.'

Can anyone help with this? I think this is more or less for someone experienced with block operations and not necessarily Parse....so I gave it my best shot with explaining the issue.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {        
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Testing"];
    [query whereKey:@"Geo" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:20];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    // Error causing
    return query;
  }];
}
```

Comment: The compiler error is because attempting to return from the block changes its inferred type to no longer match the type accepted by `-geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:` (as Vatsal said). However, the conceptual error is that you've designed `-queryForTable` to be a synchronous method that tries to return a value, but it depends on an asynchronous API that doesn't have a value to provide until some undefined future time. Asynchronicity tends to spread through a program because of that logic. What would the caller of `-queryForTable` do with the result? You'd need to do that in the block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite your logic. You cannot expect a return value from `queryForTable` method. So, in your code you should **not** be doing this :

```
PFQuery *pfQuery = [self queryForTable];
```

Instead you need to pass a completion block to your method which will be fired on receiving the Geo Location. It would go some what like this :

```
-(void)queryForTableWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(PFQuery*))completionHandler
{
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Testing"];
        [query whereKey:@"Geo" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:20];
        [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

        // Instead of return
        // return query;
        // call completion block here
        completionHandler(query);
    }];
}
```

So now you would be calling this method as :

```
[self queryForTableWithCompletionHandler:^(PFQuery *query) {
    // Now make use of query object
}];
```

I guess you need to dive into blocks a little bit to understand the implementation.
Apple has a neat [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) on this.

Comment: I have to return the query in queryForTable though according to Parse documentation for their subclass to work.

Comment: Which subclass are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to return a query the method only accepts a block with a void return type. Referencing from the Parse documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:):

The method `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:` accepts one parameter, a block with a void return type that accepts exactly two arguments; `PFGeoPoint *geoPoint` and `NSError *error`.

If you're confused about the usage of blocks, refer to the official Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Blocks.pdf). If you don't have the time to read all about blocks and how they work, [this](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com) proves to be a helpful reference point.

Comment: I've never used the Parse framework myself, but from what I understand from the documentation is that this method is used to fetch a `PFGeoPoint` object. If you want to process this object, store it in a variable or array for later use, such as in your query.

Answer (score -1):

You can't return within a block, as it's an asynchronous operation, while your function is not . This means that your above code will call geoPointForCurrentLocation on another thread, and once that's completed run the block. Your call to queryForTable, however, is on the main thread and synchronous.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, restructure your code to assign the query results to an instance variable, or implement a callback on query completion that will do what you want with the results.